# Brownian Motion is almost surely unbounded, and a proof for the discrete Random Walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

> If $B_t$ is a Brownian Motion, why we have 
>   $$
>  P(\liminf_{t\to\infty} B_t = -\infty) = 1
> $$
>   and $P(\limsup_{t\to\infty} B_t = +\infty) = 1$?

I guess for the following "discrete version" of the "Brownian motion" (which isn't called Brownian Motion but Random Walk I guess) I have an argument. Let $B_n$ with $B_n \sim \mathcal N(0, n)$. Set
$$
 A_k := \{ B_n > k \mbox{ for infinitely many }n \}
            = \limsup_n ~ \{ B_n > k \}
$$
and $A := \bigcap_k A_k$, then $\omega \in A$ iff the path of $\omega$ is unbounded, i.e. $A = \{\limsup_n B_n = +\infty\}$. Each set $A_k$ is in the tail-$\sigma$-algebra as the limsup of sets, and so $A$ as a countable intersection is a tail-event, therefore by Kolmogoroff's 0-1-law we have $P(A) \in \{0,1\}$. As for each $n$ we have
$$ 
 P(B_n > \sqrt n) = 1 - \Phi\left(\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt n}\right) > 0.1
$$
where $\Phi$ denotes the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution, and as
$$ 
 \bigcup_n \{ B_n > \sqrt n \} \subseteq A
$$
and by the above $0.1 < P( \bigcup_n \{ B_n > \sqrt n \} )$
we could not have $P(A) = 0$, therefore $P(A) = 1$. Similarly the case $P(\liminf_n B_n = -\infty) = 1$ might be establised.

In my approach I used that the process is discrete, but I do not know how to show it in the general case for continuous time. So any help would be greatly appreciated! Also if my solution for the discrete case is way to complicated I would also be thankful for feedback and alternative approaches.

Comment: It sounds like you're familiar with a similar result pertaining to the central limit theorem. It sufficies to show that the infimum is attained on a countable subsequence, so you're basically done. Just use the fact that differences of brownian motion are independent. Pick your favorite sequence $t_k$, say $t_k=k$ and look at $B_{t_k}=(B_{t_1}-B_{0}) + (B_{t_2}-B_{t_1})+\cdots + (B_{t_k}-B_{t_{k-1}})$. Divide $\sqrt{n}$ and carry over the proof.

Comment: "Divide $\sqrt n$ and carry over the proof" - is this division really necessary as $B_{t_k} \sim \mathcal N(0, n)$ holds already because of $B_{t_{i+1}} - B_{t_i} \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$?

Comment: You're right, I was thinking of a stronger result.

Comment: Since the events $\{B_n>k\}$ are not independent, Kolmogorov's zero-one law doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuous case follows from the discrete case! It's too bad you used "$B$" for both Brownian motion and the gaussians you're adding in the discrete case...

Say $B_t$ is brownian motion. For $n=1,2,\dots$ let $$X_n=B_n-B_{n-1}.$$The definition of brownian motion shows that the $X_n$ are iid gauussians. So if we let $$S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$$then you've shown (I haven't looked at your proof) that $S_n$ is almost surely unbounded. But $S_n=B_n$.

EDIT: Looked at the OP's proof of the discrete case, at the his request.

I was misled by his use of the term "random walk". What the OP calls a random walk is not a random walk at all, as I understand the term. And I don't see how what he says about his "random walk" can be right, since there's no independence assumed. (Come to think of it, perhaps the $B_n$ at that point is still supposed to represent brownian motion; if so ignore this paragraph. I assummed we were redefining $B_n$ at that point because of the words "Let $B_n$...". Except no, $B_n$ *can't* be brownian motion at that point because that would make literally trivial to get the continuous case from the discrete case...)

For the record, it's very easy to show that the $S_n$ I define above is almost surely unbounded. Hint: If $|S_n|\le k$ and $|S_{n+1}|\le k$ then $|X_{n+1}|\le 2k$. The probability of this is $p<1$, so the probability that $|S_n|\le k$ for all $n$ is $0$.

Comment: Yes, thank you, so it is a small step from the discrete case :) But would be kind if you could say if my proof is okay, and maybe give an easier one if you know one if my arguments are to involved (using Kolmogoroff's 0-1 law and so)...

Comment: @Stefan  See edited answer

Comment: Okay, thank you for your comments!

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Yes, if $B_n$ is brownian motion there then that's a random walk - hence the words "if so ignore this paragraph". But the reason it's not, or at least wasn't, so "clear" to me has to do with more than the word "Let". Think about this: If $B_n$ is brownian motion then here is an _accurate_ paraphrase of the OP's question: "I've shown that $B_n$ is unbounded for integers $n>0$. How can I show that $B_t$ is unbounded for reals $t>0$?". Surely the _blatant_ triviality of that question makes it all not so clear...

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Of course students do that. And of course we see such questions here all the time. Now. Context. The OP's trying to prove things about brownian motion - he's aware of 0-1 laws and such. In that context, the fact that he doesn't seem to realize that a set with an unbounded subset must be unbounded doesn't surprise you one bit? Not a teensy bit? In spite of that it's absolutely clear that that's what he meant?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: This is a few years old, but maybe you can answer my question regarding your answer: The thread wanted to prove that, almost surely, $lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} sup \; B(t) = \infty$. How does this follow from Brownian Motion being almost surely unbounded? It might go to $-\infty$ for some paths?

Comment: @MF14 Oh - good poiint. Say $A$ and $B$ are the events $\sup B_t=\infty$ and $\inf B_t=-\infty$. We know that $P(A\cup B)=1$. Since each of $A$ and $B$ has probability $0$ or $1$ this implies $P(A)=1$ or $P(B)=1$. But it's easy to see $P(A)=P(B)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich can you expand a bit on as to why $P(A)=P(B)$? I believe otherwise the expected value would not  be 0, but I cannot find a rigorous argument for that.

Comment: @MathR $P(A)=P(B)$ because $B_t$ and $-B_t$ have the same distribution