# Proof of Running Maximum of Brownian motion has continuous distribution without using the density or the fact that it is absolutely continuous

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, brownian-motion

I wanted to show that the running maximum say $\max_{t\in [0,1]}W_{t}$ has continuous distribution without taking help from the fact that it is absolutely continuous and has the distribution of $|W_{1}|$. To clarify, I want to just use the definition of Brownian motion and to prove this. (I am always talking about the standard brownian motion here).

Let us restrict to the set (of probability $1$ ) where $W_{t}$ is continuous.

Then I want to show that $P(\{\max_{t\in[0,1]}W_{t}=x\})=0$ for each $x\in\Bbb{R}$ .

So let us consider an enumeration of rationals $\{r_{n}\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ in $[0,1]$ and define $Q_{n}=\{r_{1},...,r_{n}\}$ .

We have that $\max_{t\in[0,1]}W_{t}=\sup_{r\in\Bbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}W_{r}$ .

Also $\sup_{r\in\Bbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}W_{r}=x\implies W_{r}\leq x\,,\forall r\in\Bbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ and for each $m\in\Bbb{N}$ , there exists $r\in\Bbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ such that $W_{r}\in (x,x-\frac{1}{m}]$ .

So I want to write $\displaystyle P(\sup_{r\in[0,1]\cap\Bbb{Q}} W_{r}=x)\leq P\big(\bigcap_{m\in\Bbb{N}}\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\{\exists r\in Q_{n}\,: W_{r}\in (x-\frac{1}{m},x]\}\big)=\lim_{m\to\infty}P(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\{\exists r\in Q_{n}: W_{r}\in(x-\frac{1}{m},x])$

$$\leq \lim_{m\to\infty}P\bigg(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\big\{\exists r\in Q_{n}:W_{r}\in (x-\frac{1}{m2^{n}},x]\big\}\bigg)\leq \lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(W_{r_{k}}\in(x-\frac{1}{m2^{n}},x])$$

$$\leq \lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{m2^{n}}=0$$

However I am having trouble making this precise and I obviously am making a mistake in the step of considering $\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}P(W_{r_{k}}\in(x-\frac{1}{m2^{n}},x])$ . Can anyone tell me how do I make it correct?. Also is there an easier way to do this? (I mean without using the fact that it has a density).

Another way I tried to think of is that if I can show that $\max_{t\in[0,1]} W_{t}=\max_{r\in\Bbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}W_{r}$ (note that I mean $\max$ and not $\sup$) , then I can do it easily as for any finitely many points  $r_{1},...,r_{n}$ , we have $P(\max_{r\in Q_{n}}W_{r}=x)\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} P(W_{r_{k}}=x)=0$ for all $n$ . So I can proceed with the countable union and conclude what I want. But this is not necessarily true for continuous functions. I mean for example , $\sin(2x)$ achieves it's maximum at $x=\frac{\pi}{4}\in[0,1]$ and not at a rational point.

**EDIT:**

I also tried the following but I am unsure of it. Consider the sets $A_{n}=\bigcap_{m\in\Bbb{N}}\bigg\{\exists r\in Q_{n}:W_{r}\in(x-\frac{1}{m},x]\bigg\}$ . Then $A_{n}$'s increase to $\bigcap_{m\in\Bbb{N}}\bigg\{\exists r\in \Bbb{Q}\cap[0,1]:W_{r}\in(x-\frac{1}{m},x]\bigg\}$ .

But $\displaystyle P(A_{n})=P\bigg(\bigcap_{m\in\Bbb{N}}\bigg\{\bigcup_{r\in Q_{n}}W_{r}\in (x-\frac{1}{m},x]\bigg\}\bigg)=\lim_{m\to\infty}P\bigg(\bigcup_{r\in Q_{n}}\bigg\{W_{r}\in(x-\frac{1}{m},x]\bigg\}\bigg)$

(We could switch the intersection over $m$ to limit because for each fixed $n$, the sets $\{\exists r\in Q_{n}:W_{r}\in(x-\frac{1}{m},x]\}$ is a decreasing sequence)

$$\leq \lim_{m\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m}\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_{k}}}=0$$ (By using a simple bound for standard gaussian that $P(X\in(a,b))\leq (b-a)$ for $X\sim N(0,1))$

Also to note that the maximum is always $\geq 0$ a.s. . So we can ignore $r=0$ and consider $r\in\Bbb{Q}\cap(0,1]$ as $W_{0}=0$ a.s.

So $P(A_{n})=0\,,\forall n\in\Bbb{N}$ and hence $P(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}A_{n})=0$ which is what is required.

Comment: Afaik, $\max$ makes sense only for finite sets. How do you define $\max_{t\in [0,1]}f(t)$?

Comment: @Snoop Max makes sense for infinite sets provided the maximum is achieved. Here $f$ or $W$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ and has to achieve it's maximum and minimum in $[0,1]$ . But I agree that $\max_{r\in\Bbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}W_{r}$ does not make sense. In any case, I do point out that it is not true by a counter example. So the last part is simply a flawed way that I tried .

Comment: I'm having a go and I'll let you know if I succeed.

Comment: I believe that the flaw in your proof is the statement "Then $A_n$'s increase to $\bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}} \{\exists r \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1] : W_r \in (x-\frac{1}{m},x] \}$."  The union and intersection don't commute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will prove (with our hands tied behind our back, as requested) that for each $x>0$, we have $P(\{\max_{t\in[0,1]}W_{t}=x\})=0$
(The case $x=0$ follows from time-inversion, for instance.)

It suffices to show that for each $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, the event
$A^{\epsilon}_x:= \{\max_{t\in[\epsilon,1]}W_{t}=x\}$ has $P(A^{\epsilon}_x)=0$, since for $x>0$,
$$\{\max_{t\in[0,1]}W_{t}=x\}=\cup_{m=2}^\infty A^{1/m}_x\,.$$
Let $H^{\epsilon}_z:=\{\max_{t\in[0,1-\epsilon]}W_{t}=z\}$ and let $\mu$ be the   distribution of $W_\epsilon$. Then by independence of increments of Brownian motion, we have
$$P(A^{\epsilon}_x)= \int_{\mathbb R} P(H^{\epsilon}_{x-y})\, d\mu(y) \,. \tag{*} $$

Since $P(H_{x-y}^\epsilon)$ could be positive for at most countably many $y$,
and $\mu$ is a continuous measure, the integral in $(*)$ must vanish.

Comment: Thanks Sir. I had dared to tag you to a separate question of mine about one of your proofs in Markov Chains and Mixing Times. Can you please take a look at it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4655088/waiting-time-pattern-in-levin-peres) .

Comment: May I ask you a question about your book: Brownian Motion, (the one cowritten with Mörters)? First I will say this will be a great resource for me in the future, so thank you. In chapter $1$ I might suggest there is some vagueness in how exactly the Brownian motion is specified. At some places you say it’s restriction to $[0,1]$ is measurable $\Omega\to C[0,1]$ where the RHS has the supremum norm topology (I don’t seem to se that in any exercises of statements, is it obvious?) but I’m not sure if you consider it an rv valued in (cont.)

Comment: Valued in the Borel-space of the topological product $\Bbb R^{[0,\infty)}$ or the measure theoretic product $\Bbb R^{[0,\infty)}$ or in the compact-open Borel space $C(\Bbb R)$ or… I am aware that conventions vary on how much measurability we desire in stochastic processes and I’d like to know what your convention is. I apologise if I’ve missed it but I haven’t seen it mentioned. The real motivation is because I want to know why it is valid to prove the Lévy modulus of continuity *using a specific model* rather than relying solely on axiomatic definition of the process.

Comment: That’s justifiable (as far as I know) only if we say: ok, the Lévy construction has the same  law as any other construction, and the statement depends only on the Brownian law, so it doesn’t matter. But to say that, we need to know what the ‘law’ is ie what is the target measurable space? Then I would need to check the theorem statement is a statement about an event in that measurable space, which is maybe nontrivial but certainly dependent on what that space is.

Comment: I can see that the Brownian motion *minus the almost sure continuity* has a uniquely determined law (ie invariant of the chosen model construction) on the topological product space $\Bbb R^{[0,\infty)}$ but after involving the continuity consideration I’m not sure what the appropriate setting implicit in that chapter is. I apologise if these comments are a bother, I am an inexperienced student.

Comment: @Fshrike A continuous function is determined by its values on a dense set. And the values of BM on the rational points certainly have the same distribution in all models.

Comment: I’ll have a think about that, thanks. Please, what is the codomain you view Brownian motion as being valued in (as a measurable rv) for the first chapter? I’m still not sure if you’re saying that the joint law of the whole stochastic process $\Omega\to\text{ some suitable function space }$ is uniquely determined, this matters on what the function space is (I see different conventions)

Comment: You can use $C[0,1]$. First check that the $B^{-1}(A_{f,r})$ is measurable, where $A_{f,r}=\{g: \|g-f\|_\infty \le r\}$.

Answer (score 1):

We recall the following facts.

- For any Brownian motion $W_t$, $\limsup_{t \to \infty} W_t  = +\infty$ (this follows from showing that $\limsup_{n \in \mathbb N, n \to \infty} W_n = +\infty$, a proof of which can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360997)).
- Time inversion : if $W_t$ is a standard BM then $B_t = tW_{\frac 1t}$ is also a standard BM.
- Time *reversal* : Notice the difference with the previous part. If $W_t$ is a Brownian motion and $T \in (0,\infty)$ is fixed, then $X_s = W_{T} - W_{T-s}$ is a Brownian motion for time $s \in [0,T]$.
- Sign inversion : If $B_t$ is a Brownian motion, so is $-B_t$.
- The strong Markov property : if $B$ is a Brownian motion and $\tau$ is a stopping time, then conditioned on $\{\tau<\infty\}$, the process $W_{t} = B_{\tau+t} - B_t$ is a Brownian motion started at the point $B_{\tau}$ and independent of the filtration $\mathcal F_{\tau}$ (generated by events that occurred "before" $\tau$) given the value of $X_{\tau}$.

Let us now use time inversion to make a local statement about the Brownian motion. As $\limsup_{t \to \infty} W_t = +\infty$ and $B_t = t W_{\frac 1t}$ is also a standard BM, $\limsup_{t \to \infty} tW_{\frac 1t} = +\infty$. Let $s = \frac 1t$, then $\limsup_{s \to 0^+} \frac{W_s}{s} = +\infty$. (all these statements occur with probability $1$, of course).

We claim now that $$\mathbb P(\limsup_{s \to 0^+} W_s \leq 0) =0$$ Indeed, if this event had non-zero probability, then $\frac 1s$ is positive for $s>0$, therefore $\{\limsup_{s \to 0^+} \frac{W_s}{s} \leq 0\}$ would also have non-zero probability, a contradiction to $\limsup_{s \to 0^+} \frac{W_s}{s} = +\infty$ a.s. This is a local statement asserting , in conjunction with the strong Markov Property, that from the right the Brownian motion ,even at a stopping time, is not going to be a local maximum.

Now, let's see how we would argue that for $x \geq 0$, the event $E_x = \{\sup_{t \in [0,1]} W_t = x\}$ has probability $0$, where $W_t$ is a standard Brownian motion. We will show that it is contained in a set of measure zero, and assuming completeness of the filtration, we will be done. Alternately, it is possible to express $E_x$ as a countable union of cylinder sets which I leave an interested reader to do.

---

Let $\tau_x$ be the hitting time of $x$, $\tau_x = \inf\{t \geq 0 : W_t \geq x\}$. We claim that

$$
E_x \subset \left(\{\tau_x \in [0,1)\} \cup \{W_{\tau_x} = x\} \cup \left\{\limsup_{t \to \tau_x^+} W_t \leq x\right\}\right) \\
\bigcup \left(\{\tau_x = 1\} \cup \{B_{\tau_x} = x\}\right)
$$

Indeed, suppose that $E_x$ occurs. Then the maximum of $W_t$ over $[0,1]$ is $x$. As $W_t, t \in [0,1]$ is a continuous function a.s., the maximum $x$ is attained. By definition of $\tau_x$, this implies that $\tau_x \in [0,1]$, and furthermore that $W_{\tau_x} = x$ since $W_{\tau_x}>x$ would contradict $x$ being the maximum.

Now, if $\tau_x \in [0,1)$ then $x$ is certainly a local maximum of $W_t$ "from the right" and this is reflected in the event $\limsup_{t \to \tau_x^+} W_t \leq x$. However, $\tau_x = 1$ could also happen with $B_{\tau_x} = x$, which we write as a separate event. Obviously, the "from the right" doesn't apply at $\tau_x=1$ because the supremum time range ends at $1$.

Handling the first event is quite easy. Suppose that the event $F_x = \{\tau_x \in [0,1)\} \cup \{W_{\tau_x} = x\}$ has non-zero probability. Then, conditioned on $F_x$, the process $B_t = W_{\tau_x+ t} - W_{\tau_x}, t \geq 0$ is a Brownian motion. However, because $W_{\tau_x} = x$, the equality $$
\left\{\limsup_{t \to \tau_x^+} W_t \leq x\right\} = \left\{\limsup_{s \to 0^+}B_s \leq 0\right\}
$$
holds by making the change of variable $s = t-\tau_x$. This has probability zero, therefore we are done. (Of course, if $\mathbb P(F_x) = 0$ then we're done as well).

Note that $x=0$ is handled by the first part, we assume WLOG that $x>0$ in the second part if it is necessary.

What about the second part? Here, we use time *reversal*. If $\tau_x = 1$ then $W_t <x$ for $t<1$. As $B_{\tau_x} = x$, this means that $W_1-W_t > 0$ for $t \in (0,1)$ (on a set of non-zero probability). Let $s = 1-t$, then we get $W_1 - W_{1-s}>0$ for $s \in (0,1)$. This is a new Brownian motion say $B_s = W_{1} - W_{1-s}$, and we have $B_s > 0$ for $s \in (0,1)$.

That's clearly an event which should have probability $0$, which is easy to see because it implies that $\liminf_{s \to 0^+} B_s \geq 0$, and by taking the negative sign, $\limsup_{s \to 0^+} X_s \leq 0$ where $X_s = -B_s$ is also a Brownian motion on $(0,1)$. That has probability $0$ by what we know, concluding the argument.

---

Perhaps this argument can be simplified in places, but it definitely avoids the *joint relation* of the process and running maximum which is required to make the conclusion that $|W_1|$ has the same distribution as the running maximum.

Comment: I was trying to avoid stopping time arguments . Can you tell me what is the problem with the method I used in the "edit" part of my question. In any case . Thanks for the answer(+1). I'll wait though for a more elementary argument if it exists before accepting the answer.

Comment: @Dovahkiin I see, maybe there might be a non-stopping time based argument, although I see it being difficult. I will look at your edited post and edit my own post to reflect those issues. Kindly give me one day, thanks.

Comment: @Dovahkiin Your efforts are *correct*, to the best of my knowledge. I believe you should add it as a self-answer.