# A 2D Brownian Motion will hit any given line on the plane with probability one.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I recently read about an interesting fact involving $2$-D Brownian Motions. If $B(t) = (B_1(t), B_2(t))$ is a two-dimensional standard Brownian motion, then $B(t)$ will hit any given line on the plane with probability one.

As an useful reference I believe [https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/coverage.pdf](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Epemantle/papers/coverage.pdf) can help. But I am not sure how to prove this!

Comment: What's your background? Do you know how to prove the corresponding one-dimensional property?

Comment: I am not sure about the corresponding 1D property

Comment: The 1D property says that a BM on the line almost surely hits every point. More astonishingly:  a BM that starts at zero hits every point (as far away as you want it to be from zero) with non zero probability instantly after $t=0\,.$ In 2D the result in your title is slightly less trivial and in 3D it does not hold. Topics you should read about are recurrence and transience.

Comment: The line is straight line or can be any curve line?

Comment: As per the question it is a straight line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remark:** We notice that a uni-dimensional Brownian Motion $W_t$ will reach the value $a\in \mathbb{R}$ almost surely. The proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1360997/195378)  (the question and the accepted answer). Indeed, as $W_t$ goes to $\pm \infty$ almost surely, $W_t$ will reach any value $a$ before a time $T_a<+\infty$.

---

Now, in the bi-dimensional case, we will prove that the bi-dimensional BM $(B_{x}(t),B_y(t))$ will hit almost surely (which is stronger than with probability $1$) the line $(d)$ passing through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ and having the direction vector $p\vec{e}_x+q\vec{e}_y$ (with $p^2 +q^2 = 1$).

Indeed, instead of using the canonical coordonnate system $Oxy$, we use the coordinates $Ouv$ defined by
$$\begin{cases}
\vec{e}_u=p\vec{e}_x+q\vec{e}_y\\
\vec{e}_v=-q\vec{e}_x+p\vec{e}_y\\
\end{cases} 
\iff \begin{cases}
\vec{e}_x&=p\vec{e}_u-q\vec{e}_v\\
\vec{e}_y&=q\vec{e}_u+p\vec{e}_v\\
\end{cases} 
$$
In this new coordinate system $Ouv$,

- the line $(d)$ is in parallel with the axis $Ou$ and perpendicular to the axis $Ov$. The direction of the line in the new plan is $ 0\cdot \vec{e}_u+ \color{blue}{(-x_0q+y_0p)}\cdot\vec{e}_v $
- The bi-dimensional $(B_{x}(t),B_y(t))$ can be expressed in the plan $Ouv$ as follows
  $$\begin{align}
  B_x(t)\vec{e}_x+B_y(t)\vec{e}_y&= (pB_x(t)+qB_y(t))\vec{e}_u +\underbrace{(-qB_x(t)+pB_y(t))}_{=:\color{red}{W(t)}}\vec{e}_v
  \end{align}$$

The process $\color{red}{W(t)}:=-qB_x(t)+pB_y(t))$ is Brownian Motion because $B_x(t)$ and $B_y(t)$ are two independent BM and $p^2+q^2 = 1$.

According to the **Remark**, the Brownian motion $W(t)$ reaches the value $\color{blue}{(-x_0q+y_0p)}$ almost surely at the time $T<+\infty$. Then, the bi-dimensional $(B_{x}(t),B_y(t))$ in the new coordinate system $Oxy$ hit the line $(d)$.

We conclude that the process $(B_{x}(t),B_y(t))$ hit almost surely the line $(d)$.

Q.E.D